# syntax for including $_SERVER filepath in jquery ajax url?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax

i am sending data to a url using jquery ajax. i want to place the absolute url using php $_SERVER. what is the syntax to do this?

**this is the file path that goes in the URL**

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/folder/file_name.php"
```

**this is the function that the file path goes in**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "",
            data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
            success: function(){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
```

what is the syntax for this?

Comment: If the target php file is in the same domain as the page you're running the ajax from, you can simply use a relative path in the url I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to get document root from PHP, you can try something like this:

**HTML:** *(Place your document root in hidden text field)*

```
<input type='hidden' name='baseurl' id='baseurl' value='<?php echo  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>'>
```

**jQuery**: *(Get document root in jQuery from hidden text field)*

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  $('#baseurl').text() + "/folder/file_name.php",
            data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
            success: function(){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
```

**If you are writing your JavaScript in PHP files, you can also try this:**

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:  "<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/file_name.php';?>",
            data: 'time='+ visitortimezone,
            success: function(){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
```

**You can also get hostname in JavaScript too:**

```
document.location.hostname
```

Comment: +1 for listing basically all possible answers. Instead of using a hidden input field, you can also just echo a global var in the document: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">var url=' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . ';</script>';` to store the PHP's `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but there isn't much point to that if you can just use `document.location.hostname` as well.

Comment: I also echoed the whole script tag inside the php, I guess it'd be easier to put it in the html and just echo the var's value itself but yes, I'm sure you already knew that. :P No problem.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: Yes. Thanks to StackOverflow :D